# Number of ways to put objects in boxes

Tags: combinatorics

So there are $n$ boxes, that are marked. On how many ways we can divide $k_{1}$ red , $k_{2}$ blue and $k_{3}$ green balls into boxes, if none should remain empty.
Also this inequality is stated: $k_{1}+k_{2}+k_{3}\geq n$

So i really don't know how to solve this combinatorial problem. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way my be to consider using the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

What you should do is distribute the $k_1 + k_2 + k_3$ balls without concern for empty boxes. That will give you some $X$ possibilities. Then you shall subtract from $X$, the number of ways you have to distribute the balls leaving at least one empty box. After that, you add again the number of ways you can distribute the balls by the boxes, leaving 2 boxes empty, and so on and so forth, always alternating between adding and subtracting.

This is a generalization of the well-known formulas:

$\tag{1}P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$

$\tag{2}P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - \\P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$

that I present here when related to probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider going with the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Say our boxes are marked $1,\ldots,n$.  Then, for a subset $S\subseteq[n]$, let $B(S)$ be the collection of arrangements of the balls into the boxes such that every box in $S$ is empty.

Then if $A$ is the set of arrangements possible (without regard to emptiness), and $G$ is the set of all GOOD arrangements, the Inclusion-Exclusion principle tells us that
$$
\begin{align*}
\lvert G\rvert&=\lvert A\rvert-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert B(\{i\})\rvert+\sum_{i\neq j}\lvert B(\{i,j\})\rvert-\cdots\\
&=\lvert A\rvert-n B_1+\binom{n}{2}B_2-\cdots\\
&=\lvert A\rvert+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\lvert B(\{1,2,\ldots,i\})\rvert.
\end{align*}
$$
This might seem more complicated; but, the benefit here is this.  Each of the sets $B(S)$ is actually fairly easy to compute, because the condition "at least these buckets are empty" just means that you need to choose an arrangement among the existing buckets.

Comment: I was thinking about using that, but had problems formulating it